# #value error in user defined function

Tags: vba, function, excel, user-defined

I wrote a VBA function that checks several things and returns a code
that triggers conditional formatting. Everything works well except
that the formula often triggers a `#value` error. It does this for all
cells containing the formula (a few thousands). The error appears
whenever I open another workbook. It sometimes happen when I don't
open another workbook.

The function is here:

```
  Function jjcheck(STDTRow As Integer, cuCOL As Integer, cuMax As Integer, trmEnd As Integer, trmEMax As Integer, worksheetSRC As String, lstCTCT As Date) As Variant
   'use in spreadsheet =jjcheck(B2,Variables!$G$4,Variables!$G$2,Variables!$F$2,"SRM",U2)
   '=jjcheck(B2,Variables!$G$4,Variables!$F$4,Variables!$G$2,Variables!$F$2,"SRM",IF(ISBLANK(U2),TODAY(),U2))
   Dim V() As String, dayMax As Integer, lookup As Date, theDiff As Integer, lstContact As String
   V = Split(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value, "-"): dayMax = V(1): theDiff = 256
   lookup = lstCTCT
   theDiff = DateDiff("d", lookup, Date): lstContact = ""
   If theDiff > dayMax Then lstContact = "Alert"
   Dim STDcu As Integer, STtrmEnd As Date, daysTOtrmend As Integer
   STDcu = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheetSRC).Cells(STDTRow, cuCOL).Value
   STtrmEnd = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheetSRC).Cells(STDTRow, trmEnd).Value
   daysTOtrmend = DateDiff("d", Date, STtrmEnd)
   If STDcu < cuMax And daysTOtrmend < trmEMax Then
       jjcheck = "CHECK" & lstContact
   ElseIf daysTOtrmend < trmEMax / 2 Then
       jjcheck = "ETerm" & lstContact
   Else
       jjcheck = "" & lstContact
   End If
End Function
```

suspecting that the error might be due to the times cell `U2` is empty,I
changed what I put for `lstCTCT` to `IF(ISBLANK(U2),TODAY(),U2)`
That did not seem to help.[The image shows what happens in the worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojz9g.png)
Thanks for any insight you can give on that.

Comment: You should consider using `ThisWorkbook` rather than `ActiveWorkbook` or even better, give your worksheets names (in the VBA editor) and refer directly to them - `wksHome.Range(...)`. The problem with `ActiveWorkbook` is that it changes depending on which workbook you have last interacted with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this makes any difference? The main change is from 
`ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`. (a few others just to tidy up)

```
Function jjcheck(STDTRow As Integer, cuCOL As Integer, cuMax As Integer, trmEnd     As Integer, trmEMax As Integer, worksheetSRC As String, lstCTCT As Date) as Variant

'use in spreadsheet   =jjcheck(B2,Variables!$G$4,Variables!$G$2,Variables!$F$2,"SRM",U2)
'=jjcheck(B2,Variables!$G$4,Variables!$F$4,Variables!$G$2,Variables!$F$2,"SRM",IF(ISBLANK(U2),TODAY(),U2))

Dim V() As String, lstContact As String
Dim dayMax As Integer, theDiff As Integer, STDcu As Integer, daysTOtrmend As Integer
Dim lookup As Date, STtrmEnd As Date

STDcu = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheetSRC).Cells(STDTRow, cuCOL).Value
STtrmEnd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheetSRC).Cells(STDTRow, trmEnd).Value
daysTOtrmend = DateDiff("d", Date, STtrmEnd)
V = Split(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value, "-"): dayMax = V(1): theDiff = 256
lookup = lstCTCT
theDiff = DateDiff("d", lookup, Date): lstContact = vbNulltring

If theDiff > dayMax Then lstContact = "Alert"

If STDcu < cuMax And daysTOtrmend < trmEMax Then
    jjcheck = "CHECK" & lstContact
ElseIf daysTOtrmend < trmEMax / 2 Then
    jjcheck = "ETerm" & lstContact
Else
    jjcheck = vbNullString & lstContact
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That seems to do it. Good explanation too. Thanks.

Comment: No problem @TMZ if you are happy that this answered your question please select the tick next to this answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks I did not know I could that. I tried to vote but could not since I am a new member. Anyway, the answer worked wonderfully for the most part. The error does not appear anymore when I open new spreadsheets. However, it still sometimes appear (less frequently). I am suspecting it is appearing whenever some "unrelated" macros in the same sheet are run. I am suspecting the other macros have the same issue than that function, but find it curious that the error appears in this "unrelated" function.

Comment: Not problem - my suggestion would be to not use ActiveSheet if possible. This means that when your function is updating in the background but you have a different worksheet active the references will be wrong.